# Перейти на 5 строку JtextArea в Java

Tags: java, swing, текст

Я думаю вы знаете функцию Go To в блокноте windows, так вот, мне нужно сделать так что-бы курсор JTextArea перемещался на 5 строку.

Answer (score 1):

#### Код:

```
    private void goTo(JTextArea textArea, char c, int ind) {
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ind-1; i++) {
            index = textArea.getText().indexOf('\n', index) + 1;
        }
        textArea.setSelectionStart(index-1);
        textArea.setSelectionEnd(index);
    }
```

---

#### Использовать:

`goTo(textArea, '\n', 5);`

---

#### Информация:

`goTo(arg0, ch1, i1);`

`arg0` - `JTextArea`

'ch1' - `char` - символ который нужно найти

`i1` - `int` - какой по счету символ нужно найти